# How to make a manipulatable map that can change color?

Tags: manipulate, map

I want to color the world map differently according to how much the number of each country. For example, USA using renewable energy for 20% should be colored lighter than Canada using renewable for 50%. However, I want it to be manipulatable too because the number changes every year. Can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange. Would you please provide a copyable form of the Mathematica code (by updating your post) that you have tried out so far. It helps to establish a reference point for the respondents. Also, please indicate where you are having difficulty so that you can get focused answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Look at [`GeoRegionValuePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRegionValuePlot.html)